# ¿Qué significa la expresión argentina "voituret copera"?

Tags: modismos, argentina

¿Qué significa "voituret copera" en el tango argentino "Pato"?:

> Ayer te vi pasar con aire de bacán
>   en una **voituret copera**.
>   Te saludé y vos te hiciste el gil
>   como si no me conocieras;

*Voituret* es una palabra francesa que significa *auto*.  Entiendo que *copera* es una mujer que trabaja atendiendo clientes en un cabaret. Sospecho que la expresión podría aplicarse a un tipo de auto francés.

Comment: Más precisamente, voituret viene de la palabra francesa *voiturette* que significa "auto muy pequeña" (carrito/cochecito).

Comment: Soy argentino, pero no sabía que existía esa frase.

Answer (score 7):

- *Bacán* puede ser el que mantiene a una concubina pero aquí es alguien que vive y viste a lo grande, de forma ostentosa[1] (que no
  es lo mismo que
  [*ostentórea*](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/pascual-ensena-a-amar-la-lengua-en-no-es-lo-mismo-ostentoso-que-ostentoreo-7343/)).
- *Voituret*, más que un auto, es un tipo de carruaje[2].
- Aunque *copera*, como sustantivo, es lo que tú indicas, aquí es un adjetivo: *lujosa*[1].

Así pues, el protagonista ve al "amigo" montado en un carruaje lujoso, bien vestido y con aire altivo, lo saluda y él se hace el tonto (el gil) y lo ignora por ser pato (no tener dinero).

Fuentes:

1. [Diccionario de
       lunfardo](https://fattiditango.files.wordpress.com/2007/05/diccionario-del-lunfardo-jerga-del-espanol-de-buenos-aires-vocabulario-tango.pdf).
2. [LUNFARDO, VESRE E OUTRAS MODALIDADES DO LINGUAJAR
   ARGENTINO](http://www.repositorio.ufc.br/bitstream/riufc/3386/1/1984_Art_MCAzevedo.pdf).

Comment: Me surge la duda si `copera` tiene relación con `copada`, que es muy usada en Argentina.

Comment: @VladimirNu Es posible que ambas vengan de _copa_, en el sentido de la parte **superior** de un árbol (que es algo que suele alcanzar gran altura comparada con la nuestra). En España (no sé si por allá también) se usa la expresión [_como la copa de un pino_](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=como+la+copa+de+un+pino) ("de mucha calidad o categoría"), que tiene un significado muy cercano a _copada_  y _copera_.

Comment: Conviene aclarar, creo, que "voituret"  fue una expresión de moda (no diría "lunfardo" en este caso) hace muchos años, por eso entró en varios tangos https://reyaller.wordpress.com/2015/08/31/voiturette-en-letras-de-tango/
Hoy se usa raramente
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIlFqZiyA9Q

Answer (score 1):

Voiturette se le decìa  a lo que hoy llamamos coupè en Argentina. Auto generalmente con capota de lona, convertible de dos puertas,elegante y potente,  preferido por los playboys. De ninguna manera un auto chiquito. Eran autos de primera. Y "copera" debe venir de copar, es decir arrasar, impresionar con, como en "copar la banca". Nada que ver con la mujer que "copea" en cabarets.  Agrego que la palabra voiturette se pronunciaba en "reo" como vuaturè, mimetizando su pronunciaciòn gala.

Answer (score 0):

La *voiture copera* fue un automovil Francés de principios de siglo. Ahora Bugatti ha fabricado la Voiture Noire, el coche más caro del mundo.

Comment: Esta entrada ganaría mucho con un enlace o refenrencia que explicase que la "oiture copera fue un automovil Frances de principios de siglo". Aparte, podrías añadir algo que no viniese ya en las otras respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El adjetivo copera en este contexto, no tiene relación con mujer que trabaja en un cabaret ganando comisión por las copas que el cliente le brinda. Ni con copa de árbol. Es el adjetivo lunfardo para decir lindo, bello, pero sobre todo elegante. Ejemplo: un hombre muy copero, qué mujer tan copera, una casa linda y copera, etc. Conocí justamente un hombre, que en los 50's le dieron sus amigos el apodo "el copero", porque andaba siempre bien vestido y peinado, o sea elegante, siempre copero. Expresión halagadora era decirle a un joven: *¡qué copero te viniste!* o *¡qué copero estás!* Detalle, estoy hablando de Montevideo, Uruguay, aunque esa jerga es compartida con Buenos Aires casi al 100 por ciento.

Comment: Mejor si podrías añadir algo que no viniese ya en las otras respuestas

Comment: ¡Bienvenido al sitio, Juan! He visto que publicaste un primer intento y dejaste la respuesta a medio escribir. Aquí las respuestas se pueden [edit]ar en cualquier momento, por lo que si te equivocas no pasa nada, editas y punto. Por otro lado, si ves que otra respuesta ya comenta lo que dices, vótala positivo, no es necesario añadir otra. Consulta las secciones [tour], [help] y [answer] para más información.

Comment: Hola, gracias. No la dejé yo a medio escribir mi primera respuesta. La escribí completa, y cuando hice el log in para mandarla, por algún problema técnico, desapareció la mitad de mi texto. Después lo escribí completo de nuevo. Entonces, fue un error del sistema. Observa que mi respuesta no repite nada de otras, pero sí intenta negar otras teorías, porque estoy seguro de lo que escribí. Entonces, es mención elucidadora. Atentamente Juan Ramirez